# Accordion like effect overlapping issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I think this may be a CSS issue, but Im not really sure.

The problem: I have a div that expands when a parent div is clicked, it does this with jQuery/CSS. When it expands, it is overlapping a footer on the page. I want to make it so that the page expands in height to accommodate the new content without overlapping the footer. So basically the footer should be moving out of the way. Any ideas?

Here is some code.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="virtualtours">
    <span id="virtualtours_title">VIRTUAL TOURS</span>
    <div id="virtualtours_videos">
      <?php include'inc.virtualTours.php'; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">...</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#virtualtours").click(function(){

        if( $("#virtualtours_videos").css("height") == "0px" ){
                $("#virtualtours_videos").css("height","240px");
        } else { $("#virtualtours_videos").css("height","0px"); }
});
```

In the CSS, everything is positioned relativly

```
position:relative;
```

Comment: btw, I tried using jQuery's accordion and i couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you check jQuery Accordion, you'll see, that each section has static height. In your case better way is strictly assign height value to #wrapper. Moreover, you have same height for each section, so, it shouldn't be problem for page design.